# how to put useQuery in react-query in conditionally using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am using `useQuery` from `react-query` to fetch data that I only want the query to run in some condition. How can I use it?
following is my code to use `useQuery`

```
  const query = useQuery<APIResponse, Error>(
    [{query: creatGQL, variables: variables}],
    async () => {
      const result: APIResponse = await ucFetch(apiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: creatGQL,
          variables: variables,
        }),
      });
      return result;
    }  );
  return query;
```

Comment: The solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69760795/16983617
It worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

A query can be disabled / enabled by using the `enabled` option. If it is `false`, the query will *not* run:

```
useQuery(key, queryFn, { enabled: myCondition }
```

the condition can be static, or driven by state / props - anything that's a boolean really.

Comment: I though enabled parameter only to determine if query should run after first time component render..it doesn't apply the situation like once component already render but not the case that useState variable change after component render

Comment: no, that's not the case. enabled can enable or disable a query at will.